# sidebar gadget - get location of html files

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm looking for a way to retrieve from inside the windows sidebar gadget environment the absolute location (i.e. on the disk) of the html files the gadget is hosting.
Sounds weird I know...
I want to "pop out" an external window from inside my COM object and show the html using a control.
This unnatural gadget behavior is due to the fact that there is no configuration possible to make the flyout window stay put if it's lost focus.